# Spark UDF not giving rolling counts properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a Spark UDF to calculate rolling counts of a column, precisely wrt time. If I need to calculate a rolling count for 24 hours, for example for entry with time 2020-10-02 09:04:00, I need to look back until 2020-10-01 09:04:00 (very precise).

The Rolling count UDF works fine and gives correct counts, if I run locally, but when I run on a cluster, its giving incorrect results. Here is the sample input and output

Input

```
+---------+-----------------------+
|OrderName|Time                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
|a        |2020-07-11 23:58:45.538|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:00:07.307|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:01:08.817|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:02:15.675|
|a        |2020-07-12 00:05:48.277|
+---------+-----------------------+
```

Expected Output

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----+
|OrderName|Time                   |Count|
+---------+-----------------------+-----+
|a        |2020-07-11 23:58:45.538|1    |
|a        |2020-07-12 00:00:07.307|2    |
|a        |2020-07-12 00:01:08.817|3    |
|a        |2020-07-12 00:02:15.675|1    |
|a        |2020-07-12 00:05:48.277|1    |
+---------+-----------------------+-----+
```

Last two entry values are 4 and 5 locally, but on cluster they are incorrect. My best guess is data is being distributed across executors and udf is also being called in parallel on each executor. As one of the parameter to UDF is column (Partition key - OrderName in this example), how could I control/correct the behavior for cluster if thats the case. So that it calculates proper counts for each partition in a right way. Any suggestion please

Comment: Can you show your UDF code ?

Comment: I can't share it entirely, its something like udf {(ordername: Partition, time: Range, Long) process:{}}, Initial Requirement for UDF, all records within same partition are sorted by date. What it does is for each partition (order name here), if new record is for existing partition, adds the record to queue, increment the count, then it checks if wrt current time, if all records so far in queue falls within 24 hours, if not then removes the records from the beginning (as it is queue)

Comment: It will be really useful if you can show : `input data/dataframe` and `expected output/expected dataframe` .

Comment: I Updated the question with input and expected output dataframes

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment , you want to count the total no of records of every record for the last 24 hours

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType

//A sample data (Guessing from your question)
val df = Seq(("a","2020-07-10 23:58:45.438","1"),("a","2020-07-11 23:58:45.538","1"),("a","2020-07-11 23:58:45.638","1")).toDF("OrderName","Time","Count")

// Extract the UNIX TIMESTAMP for your time column
val df2 = df.withColumn("unix_time",concat(unix_timestamp($"Time"),split($"Time","\\.")(1)).cast(LongType))

val noOfMilisecondsDay : Long = 24*60*60*1000

//Create a window per `OrderName` and select rows from `current time - 24 hours` to `current time` 
val winSpec = Window.partitionBy("OrderName").orderBy("unix_time").rangeBetween(Window.currentRow - noOfMilisecondsDay, Window.currentRow)

// Final you perform your COUNT or SUM(COUNT) as per your need
val finalDf = df2.withColumn("tot_count", count("OrderName").over(winSpec))

//or val finalDf = df2.withColumn("tot_count", sum("Count").over(winSpec))
```

Comment: Yes both input and outputs are data-frame, the above approach is tried long ago and it is not working on cluster with enormously large amount of data for a single partition, say 1Million records. The spark job never finishes and thats the reason, to go with UDF, reducing the number of records  by maintaining in queue, but this leaded to wrong counts probably as the data is being distributed. A way to enforce all partition data records to be processed one after another (sequential execution) would solve the problem, but not sure how

Comment: GOt your point. It's skew problem. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64349579/7094520 . The idea is to make window of just 24 hours for `OrderName`

Comment: Got it, but I have UDFs, trying to reduce the data skewness, but the problem being, partitioned data is being distributed among different executors resulting incorrect counts

Comment: Don't you think UDFs will solve the problem with the queue approach I was explaining earlier. Probably I might have to try like iterator transformation with mapPartitions, not sure how to do it, need to explore. Any suggestions? The link you shared is exactly the same problem, that might be the same person I know of who posted it. Thank you for sharing the link

Comment: I was in discussion with the person when this question was active that's why I directly recommended you the working solution :) . Do try it, it will definitely reduce the skewness.

Comment: And regarding UDF, are you talking about UDAF ? didn't understand your approach. Can you point me to a relevant blog/doc to something similar? @BhavanaSajja

Comment: Adding two windows did not work even, it's losing precision worked but we want exact precision.nor UDAF it's UDF